# Efficient Way to Process Simple but Large Files in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that has me a bit over my head performance-wise.  I'm tasked with reading large (50MB or so) files of particle coordinates and displaying them.  I'd like to use C++ for this because I am learning it already.

The coordinate structure in the files are simple, there's just alot (say a million or so):

```
1234.5667 5234.1566 //coordinate 1  
8532.6123 5152.6612 //coordinate 2  
....
```

Being a noob, I just want to read in the files line by line and store them in vectors, is this wrong?  Maybe I should be reading in the whole file first (buffered?), and then parsing the values?

Working example:

```
clock_t c1 = clock();
vector<double> coords;
double coord;
ifstream fin("file.txt");
while(fin >> coord) {
    coords.push_back(coord);
}
cout << "done. " << coords.size()/2 << " coords read.\n";
cout << "took " << (clock() - c1)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds." << endl;
```

And corresponding output on a 40MB file with 2 million coordinates:

```
done. 2000000 coords read.
took 1.74 seconds.
```

Which is fast in my mind, but I'm thinking my mind isn't a good judge.

Comment: The question is, is it fast enough? If so, you have your solution.

Comment: I'm with Neil here.  Someone somewhere has to read the data once -- after which you can play tricks like mmap to file, use something like Google's ProtoBuf, ...  But you have to get human-readable ascii to binary at least once.  And as 1.7 secs isn't _that long_ you may as well keep this for clarity.

Comment: Also, this solution scales well if the size of the input files goes up (as these things tend to), which reading the whole shebang into memory and parsing may well not do.

Comment: Awesome! I like when simple is best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to preallocate the vector using .reserve if you have an idea of how large the "average" file is.

Efficiency is a tricky game.  Don't play tricks early on, and design a good basic algorithm.  If it's not fast enough, you start looking at the IO routines, whether you're creating any "extra" objects (explicitly or implicitly, especially if you're passing parameters around).

In your example, you might want to do a second call to clock() before printing the summary output -- get a slightly more accurate timing! :)

Comment: Where would the second call to clock go?  Maybe take the average of two calls?  Confused on that one...

Comment: Immediately after the while loop.  Assign it to another clock_t variable and do the subtraction in your cout statement.  Because you are currently calling clock() in your 2nd cout statement, your reported execution time includes the first cout statement.  It's not likely to be significant compared to the time spent in the loop, but as a general rule, I/O (cin, cout, etc.) can be relatively expensive, and you don't want to include it in your timing.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you meant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your input file has fixed line widths (chars per line), then hauling in data into a buffer becomes easier.  For variable line width files, determining when to refill a buffer becomes tricky.

### The Single Buffer Method

Allocate a buffer of `char`, size = (line width) * number of lines to store.  Or you could work backwards:  Max lines in buffer =  (buffer size) / (line width).  Remember that line width may contain `'\n', '\r'` or both.

Read in the entire buffer using `fread` or `istream::read`, otherwise known as block reading.
Maintain a pointer to the "next line" in the buffer.  Increment the pointer after reading, if it goes beyond the end of the buffer, read in another block.  Repeat as necessary.

### The Double Buffer Method

Allocate two buffers.  Read one buffer.  Start processing data in first buffer.  Read into second buffer while processing first.  When first buffer processing is finished, start processing second buffer and read into first.  Repeat as necessary.

This method relies on multi-processing:  reading while processing data.  This can be implemented as two threads, or non-blocking reading (reading operation doesn't wait for completion before returning).  With threads, one thread processes while the other thread reads.  Use semaphores to single end of processing and buffer ready.

### Multiple Buffer Method

Similar to double buffer, but more buffers are allocated.  Consider this a race game.  The reading task is trying to stay ahead of the processing task.  The processing task should wait until N buffers are read before starting.  The objective is to allocate enough buffers so the processing task doesn't wait for the reader task.

### Optimization:  Loop Unrolling

You may also want to consider Loop Unrolling as another speed optimization.  Duplicate the code in the loops many times to reduce the number of iterations.

I usually wait until after the program works correctly before applying these techniques unless the program is incredibly slow, such as program requiring 1 hour to process a 2GB file (it was optimized down to 2 minutes).

Comment: -1: You are not going to improve on the buffering already being done by ifstream. You will only add overhead managing your own buffer. As for the multi-threading tactics, there is some merit, but this is probably way out of scope for the OP, and also overkill for a case where there is literally no processing to be done. Loop unrolling will not help here either, as the test for EOF still has to be done after each `>>`.

Comment: It's not hard to beat ifstream, if you know specifics of how your data is chunked.  But then, I suppose anyone who knows that can probably just readv() directly.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization should start from measurement.
Described code does three things:

1. reads some bytes from file
2. parses them as text representation of doubles
3. stores them in vector

Time share for each part should be measured.

For #1 it can be prereading file contents into memory (50M should fit and not cause swapping) and then running algorithm with time measuring. Difference will show how much takes reading from disk.

For #2 file structure temporarily can be switched to sequence of binary representations of doubles. Difference will show how much takes parsing.

For measurement of #3 std::vector::reserve could be used (actually as it has already been suggested, this could be not only measurement tool, but also optimization).

Personally I would not expect that #3 will take significant time, but measurement is better than guessing.

After detecting most time consuming part efforts may become more focused and thus more effective...

Answer (score 0):

One way you can think of to improve it is, instead of reading line by line, you can read chunks of the file in the main memory and read 'line by line' from that buffer. The size of the buffer could be the size of a cluster in your machine.

Comment: In what sense does this "improve" it?

Comment: `ifstream` is already buffering -- I think by default the buffer size equals the page size (not sure if this is true on all platforms).

Comment: Thank you @STingRaySC for the explanation, I didn't know that. Some people in this forum think we should be "clever" like then

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms, you'll get better performance by falling back to C Standard Libaray I/O (`<cstdio>`).

Barring that though, if you know how many values you are reading in from the file (or you can include the count in the file itself), you can probably improve performance by a measurable amount by initializing the vector of the appropriate size and writing directly to an iterator, like so:

```
std::vector<double> coords(4000000); 
std::vector<double>::iterator it = coords.begin();
ifstream fin("file.txt");
while (fin >> *(it++)) {}
```

Just make sure you can rely on the count, or you risk iterating past the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers already given, you might think about how you display the coordinates. Perhaps you don't need to store them in a vector before further processing?